# logrotate mysql not deleting old files

Tags: mysql, logrotate

I have set `logrotate` for MySQL as follows:

```
/var/lib/mysql/SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log {
    create 640 mysql mysql
    daily
    rotate 7
    missingok
    compress
    copytruncate
postrotate
    # just if mysqld is really running
    if test -x /usr/bin/mysqladmin && \
       /usr/bin/mysqladmin ping &>/dev/null
    then
       /usr/bin/mysqladmin flush-logs
    fi
endscript
}
```

Logs are rotating but `logrotate` does not delete old files up to 7 days, I do not understand why!

```
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  2872869960  1 janv. 03:14 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200101
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  1435092639  2 janv. 03:10 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200102
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  3327212727  3 janv. 03:15 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200103
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  3769253814  4 janv. 03:09 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200104
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  1456211047  5 janv. 03:19 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200105
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  1404786625  6 janv. 03:18 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200106
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  4857352706  7 janv. 03:50 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200107
-rw-rw----. 1 mysql mysql  1697951939  8 janv. 03:15 SITE1-L-MPKI-01.log-20200108
```

How can I force it to delete files older than 7 days?

Answer (score 0):

If you just changed the rotate value to 7, it won't delete the 8th file. You will need to do it manually. Going forward, it won't create the 8th file, however.

The way you have it configured now, `logrotate` will not look past 7 files.

Comment: Hi, i didn't change the configuration, just i have deleted the other old log files this configuration is not deleting old files